# Why is Setting state with data in a fetch using context API caught in an infinite fetch loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, react-context

[image: Provider]

This is my context provider. Within the component, I fetch local JSON data. The JSON data looks something like this:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Alan",
  "ticker": [
   "AAPL",
   "MSFT",
   "GOOG",
   "FB"
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "Madison",
  "ticker": [
    "TSLA",
    "AAPL",
    "V"
  ]
 },
 etc...
]
```

So it is just an array of objects. If I were to console log resp.json() it would come out good. If I console log data it would come out with the array of objs. which is good. BUT the moment I try using setProfile(data), the application going bonkers. Let me show you what happens when I try setting the profile with the data.
[image: Fetch loop]

I'm assuming that this is an infinite fetch loop. Not sure honestly why this is happening when I try to setProfile(data). If there is another way of doing this please let me know. All I'm trying to do is get all the profile data in the profile context so I can use it in my other components. For example I've created a dropdown which display all the names in the json file.

Comment: My first guess would be that your `useEffect` has no dependencies and fires each time your component updates/rerenders.

Comment: I have posted an answer showing you how to use the second parameter of the use effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook is missing a dependency array so it is running the callback each time the component renders, i.e. when it updates the `profile` state.

You likely want to only do this fetch once when the component mounts, so use an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const url = ".....";
  fetch(url)
    .then(resp = resp.json())
    .then(data => setProfile(data))
    .catch(console.log);
}, []);
```

Comment: It looks like this works! Also, that makes sense. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

To add a little more info to @DrewReese's correct answer, you can effectively use the dependency array to choose when to 'trigger' the useEffect. An empty dependency array will trigger only when component mounts, but you could use something like this:

```
    const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Hello World')
    }, [trigger])
```

The above will run every time you change the state of trigger. So if you had a button that did this:

```
    <button onClick={()=>setTrigger(!trigger)}>Log Hello World!</button>
```

...it would trigger the useEffect every time you click it.

When thinking about [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), I also always think it's important to think about [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), which also takes a dependency array, and can be used to move dependencies out of the useEffect block.

Comment: That is really interesting. Consider this situation; if I have a dropdown that displays "names" from the JSON data, and when you click on the names if displays the tickers that are correlated with the names. Would it make sense to use what you just did except when you click on a name it triggers a fetch to get the tickers for that user. So, in effect instead of preloading all of the tickers which may be a costly operation depending on the size of the list, we only perform a fetch when the user is selected? Or is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @korpe That seems logical, fetch only what you need. You can always cache results app-side. Depending on the backend you can even inform the browser how long to cache network requests ([cache control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)) so if it's reasonable a subsequent request would yield the same response the browser can simply return the previously cached result and skip the network.

Comment: Yeah,  I use this 'trick' all the time though to 'toggle' fetch calls. You have to bear in mind that the useEffect will run when the component mounts, but if whatever state you are using to trigger the effect starts as null, you can use a condition inside useEffect (`if (state) {...}`) to prevent that first fetch.  It would be effective for a large number of users, but depending on the number of users and the type of data, it might be more effective to fetch data for a larger number of users at a time. Fetch calls can be expensive, depending on network speed.

Comment: Because I cannot perform an async fetch inside the useEffect, if the data is of a considerable size where calling the entire data inside the useEffect would choke the application would it be better to create a separate async function and call it inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: async is fine in useEffect.. `useEffect( async () => {}, [])`